# Access property by name to work in older XCode/SDK, `safeAreaInsets`

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I started using `UIView.safeAreaInsets` in my iOS Objective-C code, but this only works with the newer Xcode/SDK versions. That is, at compile time, an older SDK won't recognize the `safeAreaInsets` property.

I'd like to retain compatibility with these older versions. I've been told I shold be able to access this `safeAreaInsets` variable by name somehow, thus avoiding the compile-time check.

How can it be done?

*I've tried selectors, and valueForKey, but can't get them working. Either they are the wrong approach or I can't figure out the syntax.*

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways to keep your code compatible with different versions. I am sure there are others as well.

The `respondsToSelector` is a runtime check to see if an object responds to a certain selector. Perhaps this is what you are looking for. Useful not only for distinguishing between different class versions, but also for detecting optional methods.

```
if ([self.view respondsToSelector:@selector(safeAreaInsets)]) {
    NSLog(@"safeAreaInsets available");
} else {
    NSLog(@"safeAreaInsets not available");
}
```

The `operatingSystemVersion` available on `NSProcessInfo`. Gives you the OS version as three `NSInteger`.

```
NSOperatingSystemVersion version = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion];
NSLog(@"Version %d.%d.%d", (int)version.majorVersion, (int)version.minorVersion, (int)version.patchVersion);
```

The `@available` keyword (or is it a macro or directive?) compiles to a runtime check of the OS version your code is running on. This method is available since Xcode 9.0.

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    NSLog(@"iOS 11.0 or higher");
} else {
    NSLog(@"below iOS 11.0");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, these are useful, but I don't need to detect if it's available, I need to access it in a way that works even if the Xcode version doesn't have it yet.  That is, I already know if it's available or not (though your respondsToSelector is good). I'm just having trouble dynamically accessing it ... note, I've found a way now, I can post my answer as well later.